# Solving CodingBat brick making puzzle in Python

Tags: python

I'm completing [this](http://codingbat.com/prob/p118406) CodingBat problem:

> We want to make a row of bricks that is goal inches long. We have a number of small bricks (1 inch each) and big bricks (5 inches each). Return True if it is possible to make the goal by choosing from the given bricks. This is a little harder than it looks and can be done without any loops.
>
> ```
> make_bricks(3, 1, 8) → True
> make_bricks(3, 1, 9) → False
> make_bricks(3, 2, 10) → True
> ```

I wrote:

```
if small + big * 5 >= goal: return True
else: return False
```

My errors are: `make_bricks(3, 2, 9)` → `False` (I put true because (2*5)+3=13 which is greater than 9.

```
make_bricks(2, 1000000, 100003) → False
make_bricks(1, 4, 12) → False
```

I found this answer than passed those tests:

```
if goal > small + big * 5:
  return False
else:
  return goal % 5 <= small
```

I dont really get why, can someone please explain?

Answer (score 12):

Here is a shorter solution.

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
    return (goal%5)<=small and (goal-(big*5))<=small
```

Comment: if possible - could you please explain your answer ?

Comment: here goal%5<=small checks whether the remainder (i.e. the remaining inches after the big brick is used) can be fulfilled by the small bricks (so if it is greater than the small bricks then it will return false else if small is greater than the remainder then it will return True as the number of bricks is sufficient).
(goal-(big*5))<=small here means to check whether the total number of inches of big bricks and small bricks are sufficient enough to complete the goal.
Instead of (goal-(big*5))<=small we can also use goal<=big*5+small as it may seem more clear and well-explained.

Comment: Adding to this as I stumbled upon this elegant solution: the best way to tackle this (for me) was to see not how we can make the question work, but how can we make it fail. There are 2 ways we can fail: if our total number of bricks is greater than the goal OR if we divided our goal by 5 (base case) and the remainder single blocks are greater than the number of smalls. Now you can use Hassan's solution by returning true if the first statement AND the second statement's opposite (instead of less than small, do greater than/equal to small) are true.

Answer (score 2):

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
    if (goal//5 <= big) and ((goal - 5*(goal//5))<= small): return True
    elif (goal//5 >= big) and ((goal - 5*(big)) <= small): return True
    return False
```

Comment: I did that with 2 conditions statements checking when the number os small blocks are less than 5 and when it is greater than 5.

Answer (score 2):

```
def make_bricks(small,big,goal):
    # for checking how much small bricks we needed we use (goal%5)
    if small<(goal%5) or (small+big*5)<goal:
       return False
    else:
       return True
```

Comment: While code only answers might provide a solution to the issue, it can be hard for others to follow along. Please consider to extend your answer and describe what your code is doing and why you chose this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't taking into account that you may not need to use all of the 5's. For example, your code fails on:

```
def make_bricks(3, 2, 9)
```

You really can only use one big brick here. This leaves you with 4 and only two small bricks to make up the difference.

That's why the working example works. It takes into account that all the 5's may not be usable.

The nice thing about codingbat is that they tell you what they were expecting and what they got during the trials. You can walk through your code with the failing values to see why it fails. Pencil and paper is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
  if (goal%5)<=small and (goal-(big*5))<=small:
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

tried and tested

Answer (score 0):

```
#Did it with recursion:

def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
    if (small + big * 5 )< goal:
        return False
    if (small + big * 5) == goal:
        return True
    return make_bricks(small-1, big, goal) or make_bricks(small, big-1, goal)
```

Answer (score 0):

This Python code works for me in the Codingbat page.

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
  small = small * 1
  big = big * 5
  while big > 0:
    if small == goal or big == goal:
      return True
    if small + big == goal:
      return True
    if small > goal:
      return True
    if big < goal and (small + big) > goal:
      return True
    big = big - 5
  if small > goal:
    return True
  return False
```

Input and Outputs:

```
Expected    Run     
make_bricks(3, 1, 8) → True True    OK  
make_bricks(3, 1, 9) → False    False   OK  
make_bricks(3, 2, 10) → True    True    OK  
make_bricks(3, 2, 8) → True True    OK  
make_bricks(3, 2, 9) → False    False   OK  
make_bricks(6, 1, 11) → True    True    OK  
make_bricks(6, 0, 11) → False   False   OK  
make_bricks(1, 4, 11) → True    True    OK  
make_bricks(0, 3, 10) → True    True    OK  
make_bricks(1, 4, 12) → False   False   OK  
make_bricks(3, 1, 7) → True True    OK  
make_bricks(1, 1, 7) → False    False   OK  
make_bricks(2, 1, 7) → True True    OK  
make_bricks(7, 1, 11) → True    True    OK  
make_bricks(7, 1, 8) → True True    OK  
make_bricks(7, 1, 13) → False   False   OK  
make_bricks(43, 1, 46) → True   True    OK  
make_bricks(40, 1, 46) → False  False   OK  
make_bricks(40, 2, 47) → True   True    OK  
make_bricks(40, 2, 50) → True   True    OK  
make_bricks(40, 2, 52) → False  False   OK  
make_bricks(22, 2, 33) → False  False   OK  
make_bricks(0, 2, 10) → True    True    OK  
make_bricks(1000000, 1000, 1000100) → True  True    OK  
make_bricks(2, 1000000, 100003) → False False   OK  
make_bricks(20, 0, 19) → True   True    OK  
make_bricks(20, 0, 21) → False  False   OK  
make_bricks(20, 4, 51) → False  False   OK  
make_bricks(20, 4, 39) → True   True    OK  
other tests
OK
```

Comment: This looks simple approach which is understandable for a new student in python - why are you using 5, what is the logic behind using 5?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
if(((small*1)+(big*5)) < goal):
    return False
elif((5*(goal//5))+small<goal):
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
if(((small*1)+(big*5))< goal):
    return False

elif((5*(goal//5))+small<goal):
    return False

else:
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully working solution in 3 lines of code:

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
  #find max number of big bricks required
  bigBrickNeeded = goal / 5;
  #check if you have enough big bricks, if not use all big bricks avaible
  bigBrickNeeded = min(big, bigBrickNeeded);
  #fill the gap with small bricks
  return small >= (goal - bigBrickNeeded*5);
```

Comment: Tested, it passes al tests

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
   bigs = big * 5
   if (bigs >= goal) and (goal % 5 <= small):
     return True   
   if (goal - small <= bigs) and (bigs < goal):    
     return True  
   else:
     return False
```

Not even as close as elegant as Haasan Razas answer of:

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
    return (goal%5)<=small and (goal-(big*5))<=small
```

** in response to "if possible - could you please explain your answer ? – N997 Mar 23 at 3:53"
All the possibilities are covered in this one line of code.  The code will return False if both case 1 AND case 2 are not True:
Case 1:  the remainder of goal divided by 5 needs to be less than or equal to small bricks. This way we have enough small bricks to cover any distance of less than 5 inches left over after big bricks are laid.
Case 2: The goal minus all the big bricks is less than or equal to small bricks. This case covers the scenario of not enough big and small to meet the goal, bit also the case where the goal can be met using only small bricks

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
   if (goal//5) <= big: 
       if (goal%5) <= small: 
         return True
       else: 
         return False
   if (goal//5) >= big:
       if (goal - (big*5)) <= small:
         return True
       else:
         return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question has been answered to death, I wanted to post my one-liner.  The logic we used was 1) find out how many large bricks will be used (up to the number available) then 2) see if there are enough small bricks to make up the difference.

The sample code allows you to code in bricks of differing lengths:

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
  smallLen = 1
  bigLen = 5

  bigs = goal // bigLen
  smallGoal = goal - (min(bigs, big) * bigLen)

  return smallGoal <= (small * smallLen)
```

You could rewrite this by smashing it together but then it's less readable (if satisfyingly small)

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
  return goal - (min(goal // 5, big) * 5) <= small
```

It is interesting that all of our approaches find the solution using the maximum number of large bricks, and this does satisfy the question, but there could be other combinations of large and small bricks that give a correct answer.  The problem does not specify that you should use all the large bricks.  I suppose you would loop through the range of large bricks, and determine for which if any of a number < big large bricks the result is also correct.

Answer (score 0):

> def make_bricks(small, big, goal):

`b=big*5`

`s=small*1`

`if b==goal or s==goal:

```
 return True
```

if b==0:  #0

```
if s>=goal:

 return True
```

if s==0:

```
return b>=goal
```

`if b<goal:`

```
if (b+s)>=goal:
  return True
else:
  return False
```

if b>goal:

```
 if ((b+s)-goal)%5==0:
   return True
```

else:

```
return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):

  def b_req(big, goal):
    req = goal // 5
    if req <= big and req > 0 :
      return req
    else:
      return big
  if goal < 5:
    s_req = goal
  else:
    s_req = goal - ( b_req(big, goal) * 5 )

  if small + big * 5 < goal or s_req > small :
    return False
  elif s_req <= small :
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
  if big*5 > goal:
    big = goal//5 
  return big*5 +small >= goal
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code snippet. It will be also great if, in addition, you give brief explanation of what was the reason of the problem.

Comment: the idea is that the number of big bricks you will use is just equal to (goal / 5 ) if the goal is divisible by 5,
            or the number big bricks is  (goal // 5) if the goal isn't divisible by 5 and the  inches the big bricks can build (big*5) is bigger than the goal, and we will complete the wall with smallbricks,
       if the inches big bricks can build is less than the goal we will complete the wall with small bricks
,   i hope i didn't make it harder for you

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):

#If you can do with all small, go for it
    if (small >= goal):
        return True

#If small are not enough, find out how many big and small combos
    rem = goal%5
    if (big*5 >= goal):
       if(small >= rem):
          return True
    else:
       if (small >= goal-(big*5) ):
          return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):

   new_goal = goal - (big * 5) 

   if 5*big > goal:
     new_goal = goal % 5

   return new_goal <= small
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
  
  if (goal > big*5 + small) : return False   #You do not have enough bricks to make the goal
  if (goal % 5 > small) : return False       #You do not have enough small bricks to make the goal
  
  return True                                # In all other cases i.e. when all the failure cases above have been taken care of
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
  big_used = min(goal / 5, big)
  small_used = min(goal - big_used * 5, small) 
  return big_used * 5 + small_used == goal
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem states that it can be solved without loops. This solution works for me but may not be the most efficient:

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):
  if (big*5) + small == goal:
    return True
  elif (goal//5) >= goal:
    return True
  elif small >= goal:
    return True
  else:
    bn = goal//5
    sn = goal - (bn*5)

    if big>= bn and sn<=small:
      return True
    elif big < bn and goal<= (big*5) + small:
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is looking for an *explanation*, not simply for working code.  Your answer provides no insight for the questioner, and may be deleted.  Please [edit] to explain what causes the observed symptoms.

Answer (score -2):

```
def make_bricks(small, big, goal):  

   b=big*5
   s=small*1

   if b==goal or s==goal:   
       return True

   if b==0:  #0
       if s>=goal: 
           return True

   if s==0:    
       return b>=goal

   if b<goal:   
       if (b+s)>=goal:
           return True
       else:
           return False

   if b>goal:
       if ((b+s)-goal)%5==0:
           return True
   else: 
       return False
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you post an answer, try to check that you are replying to the user question. In this case, the user is asking `I don't really get why, can someone please explain?`. Do you think that your reply is answering? And you post it 2 times... In this case, there are 16 more answers, so expose the Pros oy your P.O.V.